# how to use Likert Scale to prove hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likert

How to use data collected from likert scale (five point) to prove hypothesis. 
For example. 
Hypothesis 1: Internet marketing is cost efficient. 
Statement 1: internet marketing required less budget.
Statement 2: internet market enabled to reach more customers.
etc.

Comment: What relationship between Likert responses and usefulness of internet marketing? Do you have subjects randomized into 2 groups, one reached through internet marketing and one not?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Could you provide more information about the analysis? It is not clear. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @BruceET in the above example, statement were made to check if internet marketing is cost effective. There is no two groups.

Comment: One thing you might want to consider:  Do you want to combine the scores of several statements?  Or treat each statement separately?

Comment: @SalMangiafico Combine score of several statements to draw conclusion/support/disapprove the hypothesis. 
Example: Combine score of statement 1, Statement 2, Statement 3  to support hypothesis 1. 
All statement are related to Hypothesis..

Comment: In that case, you will be combining Likert "items" into a Likert "scale".  The term "Likert scale" is used in different ways, so be careful when looking for information.  Usually, the responses from Likert items are summed or averaged for each respondent into one value for the scale for each respondent.  From there, you might use a one-sample Wilcoxon test or one-sample t-test to determine if the responses differ from some neutral value, perhaps "3".